# Click Event of a Button Over another After Visibility Change

Tags: c#

I am developing a windows form application in C#. I have a big button "MainButton" which has a background image to reflect its main functionality. Inside this main button I have included 3 other small buttons which I named "CreatButton", "UpdateButton" and "DisplayButton".

When the user moves the mouse inside the big button, I am showing all small buttons otherwise when the mouse leaves the big button I am hiding the small buttons. Please see the code below.

**MY problem is that when user moves the mouse inside the big button, the click events of the small buttons dont' work.**

**Note: I also tried replacing the big button with a picture box but unfortunately it didnt' work as well.**

Any help is really appreciated.

```
  private void MainButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateButton.Visible = true;
        UpdateButton.Visible = true;
        DisplayButton.Visible = true;
    }

    private void MainButton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateButton.Visible = false;
        UpdateButton.Visible = false;
        DisplayButton.Visible = false;           
    }

    private void CreateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // do something ..
    }

    private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           // do something ..
    }

    private void DisplayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          // do something ..
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a panel control with an image background. Just bear in mind that if you use `Mouse_Leave` on the panel control then when you hover over the button the `Mouse_Leave` event of the panel will be fired and the buttons will flash on and off and you won't be able to do anything.

You can get over this by determining the control under the mouse pointer and not doing anything if it's one of your buttons.

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point pnt);

    private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(Control.MousePosition);
        if(hWnd !=IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Control control = Control.FromChildHandle(hWnd);
            if (control != null)
            {
                if(control==buttonOne || control==buttonTwo || control==buttonThree )
                    return;
            }
        }

        this.buttonOne.Visible = false;
        this.buttonTwo.Visible = false;
        this.buttonThree.Visible = false;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.buttonOne.Visible = true;
        this.buttonTwo.Visible = true;
        this.buttonThree.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control=(Control)sender;
        MessageBox.Show(control.Text);
    }
```

Comment: thanks Charlie that really solved the problem BUT just one more thing on the panel leave event the three buttons disappear one by one slowly. I wonder if there is a way to make them disappear faster and together. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the code that I've done. Are you doing anything else during the leave event?  Could you post your code and I'll have a look